# How to use recyclerview inside a collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

The speed is very very slow when I load and in some devices the application crashes and in some devices it works good.

Kindly give an idea that what is going wrong in it or suggest me a link to use recyclerview inside a collapsingtoolbar layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="#000"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:src="@drawable/a"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/filter1"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/filter"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sierch"
                android:id="@+id/search"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">


            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >




                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Prceint 12,Bahria Town Lahore Pakistan"
                    android:id="@+id/Location"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Price:"
                        android:id="@+id/price1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Rs 30,0000"
                        android:id="@+id/price"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#f74343" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Negotiable"
                        android:id="@+id/iaNegotiatiable"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:textColor="#3FB50B" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#E1E1E1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Building Year"
                        android:id="@+id/buildyear1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="2005"
                        android:id="@+id/buildyear"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <View    android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#E1E1E1"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="number of floors"
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:id="@+id/numberOfFloors"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#E1E1E1"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:src="@drawable/beds"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="Beds"
                            android:id="@+id/textView9"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:id="@+id/bedrooms"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View    android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#E1E1E1"
                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/baths"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="Baths"
                            android:id="@+id/textView11"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:id="@+id/bathrooms"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View    android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#E1E1E1"
                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/garages"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="Garrages"
                            android:id="@+id/textView13"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:id="@+id/garrages"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View    android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#E1E1E1"
                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                            android:src="@drawable/size"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="Lot size"
                            android:id="@+id/textView15"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:id="@+id/lotsize"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#EBEBEB">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Appliances"
                        android:id="@+id/textView17"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:id="@+id/spinner" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/appliances"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/downarrow"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="2 Ac "
                        android:textColor="#4D4D4D" />
                    />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Available From"
                        android:id="@+id/textView18"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="24 may 2016"
                        android:id="@+id/availableFrom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#E1E1E1"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Description :"
                        android:id="@+id/textView20"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="ghgagha ahjhajhjss sjahjsah aahsjjhaj shhjajasj dahahdjaj  agsjja adhjahjaj dahjajd ahhdjhaj adddhgauduuw uwuu hdhhudhuhd"
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>





    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/viewonmap"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:text="view on map"

        android:layout_weight="0.18" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:padding="5dip"

        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/contactinfo"
        android:padding="5dip"
    android:gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
       android:text="contact info"
        android:layout_weight="0.18" />
</LinearLayout>
```